# UITableViewCell override: when alloc UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to show `UITableviewCell` from `nib` file. And also want to add dynamic label on it. But the label is override it self.
Please provide me any method where I can call `UITableviewCell` from `nib` and also add dynamic label.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ItemCell" bundle:nil];
[[self tblView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


#pragma mark

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
   }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section                {
return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {

 return 150.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ItemCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0*i, 150.0, 20.0)];
    lbl.text=@"This is custom cell.";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ? That all your cells have the same text ?

Comment: UILabel text getting bold when reload tableview.

Comment: Problem is because you are reusing tableviewcells. But not reusing the created label. try to reuse UILabels as below answer.

Comment: It's overlapping labels each time.

Comment: I want to add dynamically UILabel by nib file it is not possible. The UILabel count may be more than one. Please see code. The Number of UILabel depends upon data base.so by nib it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath 
{
UILabel *lbl; 
ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 60.0)];
    lbl.tag = indexpath.row; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
} 
lbl = (UIlabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexpath.row]; 
lbl.text=@"This is custom cell.";
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 ItemCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];

 UILabel* label = (UILabel*)[cell.containtView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
 if(!label) {
   UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 60.0)];
   lbl.text=@"This is custom cell.";
   lbl.tag = indexPath.row
   [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
 }
 label.text = @"your text";
 return cell;
}
```